# Devise 4.1.1 with devise_invitable 1.5.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, authentication, devise, devise-invitable

I installed devise_invitable 1.5.2 with devise 4.1. Gem installed successfully, but when i run server i am getting following error:

`alias_method': undefined method`attributes_for' for class `Devise::ParameterSanitizer' (NameError)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was getting same error with devise 4.0 and devise_invitable 1.5. I fixed this error by installing latest version of devise_invitable 1.6.0 . Now it works with devise 4.0. Hope this will work for you.

I followed this [link](https://github.com/scambra/devise_invitable/issues/645)

Comment: Thanks. devise_invitable 1.6.0 is working fine with devise 4. It saved my day.